# Helix toolkit: Importing OBJ file gives odd UV results in diffuse texture map

Tags: opengl, helix-3d-toolkit, helix

The link below is a 7zip package containing the blender scene, exported obj file, material and textures. When I load the obj in MeshLab it looks great although the normal bump map does not appear to work in meshlab, the diffuse texture is perfect. When I load the obj in the helix3d toolkit the results I get are less than perfect the UV mapping appears to be almost correct but then is completely wrong in other places.

I checked all the UV coords are in 0-1 range.

[obj export 7zip package](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d20brn0mzac4l2a/traverse.7z?dl=0)

Also does normal/bump mapping work correctly in Helix3D viewport?

Comment: Vertically/Horizontally flipping the texture in either or both axes does not help.

I've also included the 3ds file export, it seems loading that in helix does not load the materials, this is a separate issue and not one I want to get into just now but I thought I would mention it for completeness.

Comment: Im not sure why you voted this down genpfault, but I have done a lot of research into this, I've compiled the Helix toolkit locally and checked out all the fixes others suggested in other threads about changing the tiling mode on the texture loader, also about flipping the texture to have opengl style uvs. I also went through checking the model in MeshLab which other threads suggested. I've posted the offending model and tagged it this thread accordingly. Please can you explain why you voted it down as you left no comments and it doesn't make sense to me,  it might put others off reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, actually its an issue with blender, for some odd reason creating a new scene in blender re-importing just the geometry and then re UV and set-up a new material with new textures then export and the mesh appears fine.

Not sure what was so wrong with it if meshlab could load it but its resolved.